# The map is loaded gmap

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, google-maps

I am using Gmap.Net in wpf.
And i need to save an image when tha map is loaded, but

```
gmap.isLoaded
```

gives nothing.

I just always get the result =>
[pict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpnXt.png)
What should I use to avoid it.

Used

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

But the time is always different and not always it shows all the map

Comment: What version / framework of .net are you using?

Comment: Version  - 4,5 @Snympi